# Is there a way to host and access a Helm Library Chart or Chart Repository using a private git repository or private AWS ECR/OCI registry?

Tags: shared-libraries, kubernetes-helm

I have helm charts across multiple repos and many of the templates and yaml files are repeated. I would like to follow the DRY principle and put all these common templates/yaml files into a library chart that can be accessed from a private git repository or AWS ECR/OCI registry.

Looking at the [Helm documentation for dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/) and the documentation for [Chart Repositories](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/) and [Library Charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/), it looks like library charts can only be used and imported from your local filesystem and Chart Repositories cannot just be hosted using a private git repo.

Is there anyway that I can host a library chart in either a private git repository (this would be the prefered way I think) or an AWS ECR/OCI registry (the [Bitnami Common Library Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/common) is stored in an oci registry)? I would obviously need to be able to import the library chart and it's templates using something like this in the `Chart.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  - name: common
    version: 1.x.x
    repository: oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts
```

I could include a library chart within each of my helm chart repositories and store some repeated yamls and templates in there which I could then import using this: `repository: file://../mylibchart`. This would then allow me to eliminate a large amount of repeated code, however, my question still stands. The ideal solution would be store all these yamls/templates in a separate single library chart that could be imported under `dependencies` for all my other Helm chart repos.

Comment: Library charts can be imported the same way as any other dependency.  Any chart repository will work.  It's true that a Git repo on its own can't do it, you need an HTTP server as described in your "Chart Repositories" link.

Comment: @DavidMaze is it possible to host a library chart in an OCI registry? It doesn't show this in the Helm documentation, but clearly bitnami and other charts do this

Comment: There's very little actually special about library charts, and I would expect this would work, but I don't have personal experience here.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ok cool. After doing some thinking I've come to the same conclusion that it just a chart, so it is probably possible. I'll have a try at it in the next couple of days and update this question with my results. 
If it does work, maybe I'll submit a change to the Helm docs (if that's even possible)

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm-www is the documentation repository.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload a library chart to a private ECR OCI registry and pull it as a dependency.

I am using AWS so here is my example of using it.

In AWS, I have uploaded a library chart to a repository (lets call it `dev/my-library-chart`):
[image: AWS ECR screenshot]

In my `Chart.yaml` in my Helm chart I have referenced the registry like this:

```
dependencies:
  - name: my-library-chart
    version: 0.0.1
    repository: oci://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev
```

Notice how the `name` and `version` of the chart are defined separately from the rest of the registry URL. When you run `helm dependency update`, you should see this in your terminal:

```
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading my-library-chart from repo oci://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev
Pulled: <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/my-library-chart:0.0.1
Digest: sha256:<hiding-my-digest-hash-here>
Deleting outdated charts
```